# Boost asio::: async_read или std:::async boost asio::read

Tags: boost, asio

Здрааствуйте,
Подскажите пожалуйста, чем принципиально отличается использование следуюших строчек кода:

```
async_read(socket, buffer(data), ec);
...
io_service.run();
```

То есть асиннхронный read.

От:

```
void boost_read(&socket)
{
read(socket, buffer, ec);
}

main()
{
future<void> read = async(launch::async, boost_read,       move(socket));
...
read.get()
}
```

То есть синхронный read отправляем в асинхронный std async.

Есть ли между этими случаяси принципиальная разница ?